# Regex for any number of numbers including dots followed by whitespace and then an opening bracket?

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

```
word-3.3.7          (in xyz)
word-3.30.7          (in lib)
word-3.56          (in pwd)
word-3        (in abc)
word          (in lib)
word-32.3          (in pqr)
word-32.3.5          (in sfw)
```

I want to `grep` capture these output from a list of random text.

Basically a grep regex that captures the following generalised text:

word||word-[any number of numbers with '.'] [any number of space/whitespace characters] [(in ]

I tried:

```
egrep "word [(in ]|word-[0-9].[0-9].[0-9] [(in ]"
```

But its not really efficient as the whitespaces are limited.

Comment: `awk -F'[-[:space:]]' '/^word-[0-9.]+ *\(in.*\)$/{ print $2 }' file`?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: which thing you want number includes a dot or any number without the dot like word-3        (in abc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `grep`:

```
grep -oE '^([_[:alnum:]]+|[_[:alnum:]]+-[.0-9]+)[[:space:]]+\(in' file
```

```
word-3.3.7          (in
word-3.30.7          (in
word-3.56          (in
word-3        (in
word          (in
word-32.3          (in
word-32.3.5          (in
```

**Regex Details:**

- `^`: Line start
- `(`: Start a group
- `[_[:alnum:]]+`: Match 1+ word characters
- `|`: OR
- `[_[:alnum:]]+-[.0-9]+`: Match 1+ word characters followed by `-` and 1+ digits or dots
- `)`; End group
- `[[:space:]]+`: Match 1+ whitespace characters
- `\(in`: Match a literal `(` and `in`

Answer (score 1):

With `GNU` grep you can use:

```
grep -oP '^word(?:-\d+(?:\.\d+)*)*\s+\(in' word 
word-3.3.7          (in
word-3.30.7          (in
word-3.56          (in
word-3        (in
word          (in
word-32.3          (in
word-32.3.5          (in
```

where `word` is the file:

```
some stuff
more stuff
word stuff
word-3.3.7          (in xyz)
word-3.30.7          (in lib)
word-3.56          (in pwd)
word-3        (in abc)
word          (in lib)
word-32.3          (in pqr)
word-32.3.5          (in sfw)
word-2 stuff
more stuff
some stuff
```

**Explanations:**

- `-oP` are used to display only the output and to use perl style regex
- `^word` lines starting with `word`
- `(?: )` non capturing group
- `-\d+` a dash followed by several digits matching for example `-3`
- `(?:\.\d+)*` this will match `.30` or `.30.7`, a dot followed by some digits appearing 0 to N times
- `\s+\(in` space characters followed by a `(` and `in`

**Demo:**

https://regex101.com/r/0fYFcD/1/

Note: This regex is a bit more restrictive than the one of [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) as it imposes that the line starts exactly with `word`